# weblogic 12.c Deployment could not be created. Deployment creator is null

Tags: weblogic

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Deployment could not be created. Deployment creator is null.
Message icon - Warning Errors were encountered while performing this operation.
```

Any information on what a *deployment creator* is and why is it not recognizing the deployment of a simple war file would be welcomed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug manifests itself if the application being deployed fails *initial* activation ("activation" of the configuration changes in the admin console). For example, if you've forgot to configure required datasources etc. and application didn't start with some error because of it.

If you see "deployment creator is null" the only remaining option is to remove the application and deploy it again. Fixing configuration without redeploying application won't help.

Once the app started successfully, "deployment creator" won't harass you anymore.

Comment: This is not a bug, it's just an error message from Weblogic without clrarity about what it going on. To fix this issue, one needs to check the server logs and see what is happening. It's likely an issue with web.xml or some other descriptor file in your application.

Comment: On the initial application startup you will see the error, yes. Any subsequent attempts will fail with the said error without actual attempt to start the application. The latter is what makes it a bug: WL must assign deployment creator no matter what, otherwise it corrupts internal application configuration. Obviously, it does not do it if initial activation fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the source of the failure (why the app failed to start) by looking in the server logs.  Or, if deploying in Eclipse, look at the Console Eclipse=>Console=>"Oracle Weblogic Server at localhost".

Comment: Or, if you're running weblogic with a startup script, the logging is likely to happen in the console that gets opened.