# getPart() returns null on uploading a file using servlets i have included @MultipartConfig but still it returns null

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic12c

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.oreilly.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
@MultipartConfig
@WebServlet("upload")
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
         Part filePart =req.getPart("fileName");
         String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("file");
        MultipartRequest mpr = new MultipartRequest(req,realPath,500*1024*1024);
        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request



        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            out.println(filePart.getName());
            out.println(filePart.getSize());
            out.println(filePart.getContentType());

            // obtains input stream of the upload file
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }
        out.println("<html><body>");
        //out.println(fileName);
        out.println("File uploaded successfully");
        out.println("</body></html>");

    }
}
```

and the html is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>form</title>
<body>
<h2>Upload Contribution</h2>
          <br><br>

          <p>Contribution Domain: <input type="text" name="contdomain">
          <br>
          <br>
          Contribution Name: <input type="text" name="contname">
          <br>
          <br>
  <form method="post" action="upload" name="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileName"><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

and the web.xml is

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FileUploadServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

kindly help me to resolve this problem... all where i have searched it asks to add @MultipartConfig but adding it still doesnt give the result.

i need the file name so that i cud add the file to database

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with Servlet declaration, you can remove `<servlet></servlet>` tag from web.xml file (with everything what's inside), and add the following proper annotation at the top of your Servlet class, so here is full version, which works on my machine:

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
@MultipartConfig

@WebServlet(
        name = "FileUploadServlet",
        urlPatterns = { "/upload"},
        loadOnStartup = 1
)
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        Part filePart =req.getPart("fileName");
        InputStream inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="upload" name="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileName"><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>App</display-name>

</web-app>
```

Comment: It gives error at deployment time.. weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Deployment could not be created. Deployment creator is null.

and i have made many other servlets using the web.xml i posted previously and all work completely fine. infact in the code posted above file gets uploaded only getPart() is returning null.

Comment: please check this question, as it seems you need to redeploy your application: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13036207/3779419

Comment: when i deploy my application with the previous web.xml it works completely fine... it gives deployment error only with this type of web.xml and the deployment error is related with the web.xml

Comment: Do you have the current version of JDK (at least 6) ?